# Is there guarantee heap allocated block address will not change(implicitly)?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, memory-address, consistency

The title isn't very clear, would have stretched a lot, but I am asking in a specific context - no user explicit memory reallocation is being performed. The chunk is allocated only once, is not appended to or anything, the question is, will its address remain the same?

The reason I am asking is I am considering a small optimization for a VM, when global data is first allocated, initial calls to functions are stores as offsets from the base pointer, but the first time they are executed, the value is cached and the instruction is changed to direct call to save the extra calculation every time. So, that data needs to persist in order for the optimization to work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, otherwise pointers would be useless, and you would need a lock/unlock mechanic to use them (like in C# where there is the `fixed` keyword that makes an object unmoveable)

Answer (score 1):

The address will not change. Once you have requested a block of memory from the memory pool it is yours to play around with -- the OS will not touch it again until you `free` it.

If you look at `realloc`, it is a funny function. It can "append" a block of memory to your existing block of memory if the addresses are available -- otherwise it will find a whole new block of memory of size `s`. The block of memory after `realloc`ing is **not always** guaranteed to be the same.

**Remark:** If you `malloc` a block of memory of a size `s` and `free` it you are not guaranteed to get the same block of memory if you `malloc` another block of the same size `s`.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to, unless using a custom allocator and emplacing.

Comment: @user2341104, It will not change. Keep in mind that `realloc` may change your block of memory rather than append to it. But aside from that, the answer is all here -- it never changes.